# How can I fix a query parsing error when sending SQL query via queryParams in WebClient/RestTemplate with Spring Webclient?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-string, apache-httpclient-4.x, spring-webclient

**Sending SQLQuery via queryParams in WebClient/RestTemplate throwing query parsing error.
**

I am getting error while parsing sql query via queryParameters in HttpClient like WebClient or RestTemplate. It is working fine if I give hardCoded sequence after "?" in URL itself. API is working fine but unable to parse the query via queryParams.

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/query"
HashMap<String, String> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
String sqlQuery = "select count(*) from TableA where abc = true"; // sql query
queryParams.put("query", sqlQuery);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();

String result = webClient.get()
                         .uri(url, queryParams)
                         .retrieve()
                         .bodyToMono(String.class)
                         .block();
```

I was expecting a successful result but thrown error for parsing query. Other queryParams are working fine. I am facing this issue just with the queryParam containing sqlQuery.

Comment: Please show us THE ERROR

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO questions must be about programming, please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)